# Does the series get unbounded if $L > 1$ in the root test?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

The root test states the following:

> Consider a series $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n$ and denote $L := \limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$. If $L < 1$, then the series is absolutely convergent, and if $L > 1$, the series is divergent.

However, I am interested in the finer question concerning the "badness" of the divergent case: For $L > 1$, can I comment anything on the boundedness of the sums $\big|\sum_{n = 0}^k a_n\big|$ as $k\to\infty$?

All I can seem to say is that we'll have a subsequence $(a_{N_k})$ for which the sums $\big|\sum_{n = 0}^k a_{N_k}\big|$ will be unbounded as $k\to\infty$. (Choose $a_{N_k} > L - \epsilon > 1$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_k$ is bounded then so is $(a_n)$ because $a_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_k-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} a_k$. But if $L>1$ and we pick $C$ such that $1<C <L$ then $|a_n| >C^{n}$ for inifnitely many $n$ so $
(a_n)$ cannot be bounded.

Comment: Note that your answer is a bit incomplete since for once the limsup property only implies that infinitely many $n$ satisfy the $|a_n|>C^n$ property, not all sufficiently large and second that similarly you are guaranteed to have some unbounded partial sums, but you also can have bounded ones and it's easy to have examples where most partial sums are bounded

Comment: @Conrad  Thank you very much for pointing out. I was careless.